Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard Will Not Boot From Disk Or USB Drive
My A1311 iMac (Mid 2010) can not boot from internet recovery nor snow leopard usb restored iso image from archive and even flashed the usb no matter what stuck on apple logo not even loading circle! Tried to then restore to disk but that still would not work

I would find it helpful to have some more detail of the steps you have taken and the errors which prevented you from proceeding. It is important to have the correct OS X image for your iMac - e.g. it needs to be at least 10.6.3 and preferably an image of the DVD which came with your model of iMac.

Have you read https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73176/snow-leopard-install-hangs and some of the other "related" questions.

What's the history here? Why does the iMac not have an OS on it now? When did it last work, and what happened since? 2010 iMacs will only have Internet Recovery if the firmware has been updated.
